# Is there a way to sandbox Wine in OS X?

Tags: osx, wine, sandbox

Wine [does not sandbox](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#How_good_is_Wine_at_sandboxing_Windows_apps.3F) the applications run therein, and is susceptible to [malware](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Is_Wine_malware-compatible.3F).

Is there a way to sandbox Wine in OS X, using some neat solution, perhaps third-party software?

Or, is virtualization software absolutely necessary?

(Unfortunately, in my case, virtualization software is something I would like to avoid, because I have limited space on my drive and it would be a waste of space to install a Windows image just to test some minor things.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `VM` is the only secure solution.

You could use [chroot-ed](http://galvanist.com/post/56925855686/chroot-jails-on-os-x) setup to isolate the app in question from the rest of your system, but remember, that if that app is clever enough to detect that it runs under `wine`, that `wine` is running under `OSX` and, finally, it succeeds to break the `chroot` jail then you are at risk.

Although the probability of such a situation is quite low, it is still possible.

Edit:

also remember to disable (at least password-protect) any networking services your `OSX` is running that may accept connections from the `localhost` without authentication